# Translate int value 100 to 0 and 0 to 100

Tags: c#, variables, math, calc

I would like to find a good way how I can best translate an integer value. I have a method TranslateValue in which comes a value 100. now the weird part of the number hundred is to increment the who from 0 to 100 and if the value that comes in the method is for example 0 then the value is 100 which the method returns. So in short I want to have a counter method that calculates the other way around I have failed many times but I can't find a good way that works

```
    int currentValue = 0;

    private int TranslateValue(int valueToTranslate)
    {
        if (valueToTranslate > 0)
        {
            currentValue++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentValue--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are describing. Maybe try to clarify and show more inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: `return 100 - value;`..?

Comment: Your question is not very clear I'm afraid. Could you pls add the expected output for 0, 50 and 100? Also, I would suggest to return a value, rather than changing the value of a global variable.

Comment: No idea what you mean or what your problem is when you tried yourself.

Comment: i wanted to reverse the calculation from 100 to 0 and 0 to 100 return 100 - value; helped a lot thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map a value from 0 to 100 to the inverse range 100..0, simply

```
return 100 - value;
```

You may wish to add suitable checks around that, or just clamp the output to 0..100 with

```
return Math.Min(100, Math.Max(0, 100 - value));
```

Comment: `return Math.Clamp(100 - value, 0, 100);` is a shorter version